# Line duplication code for emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write my function for line duplcation. I have to maintain the cursor position. This is the code in the .emacs file :

```
(defun line-duplicate
  "line duplication."
  (setq position (point))       ;Store the original position of cursor               
  (global-set-key "\C-d" "\C-a\C-k\C-k\C-y\C-y")
  (goto-char position)            ;move the cursor to original position
)

(line-duplicate)
```

However, some error is arising. What is the mistake?

**EDIT**

Just discovered the command-execute function:

```
(defun line-duplicate ()
  (interactive)
  (setq position (point))
  (command-execute (kbd "C-a C-k C-k C-y C-y"))
  (goto-char position)
)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'line-duplicate)
```

And this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global-set-key` takes two arguments, `KEY` and `COMMAND`. `COMMAND` is not a key sequence, it is a function (*usually it is a symbol naming an interactively-callable function*, says the documentation). You probably do not want to change the behaviour of <kbd>C-d</kbd> when the function is called, you want to bind the function to the key.

Comment: but then I had this earlier: (global-set-key "\C-d" "\C-a\C-k\C-k\C-y\C-y\C-p\C-p") This worked perfectly fine except the repositioning part.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to bind line duplicate to `C-d`.

You can write the following function:

```
(defun my:dublicate-line ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
  (let ((begin (line-beginning-position)) (end (line-end-position)))
    (move-beginning-of-line 2)
    (insert (concat  (buffer-substring-no-properties begin end) "\n")))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'my:dublicate-line)
```

Comment: Thanks. But my aim was to implement my own line-duplicate to get going with elisp.

Comment: @I'llsudeepdino008 Look at your code.  Now look at this code.  See what the differences are?  Try to figure out why.  Then you'll have "gotten going with elisp".